# Confirmed Registered COM Object CoCreateInstance returning REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an ATL DLL that I am trying to consume from an ATL Exe.  When I try to create an instance of the object in the DLL it fails with an error REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. I have checked the registry and I can see the object is registered, both the ProgID as well as the CLSID.

```
CComPtr<IMyInterface> ptrMyInterface;
ptrMyInterface.CoCreateInstance(L"ProgID", nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL); // Fails

CLSID myClsid;
CLSIDFromString(L"{MyCLSID}"), &myClsid);  // Correctly looks up the CLSID
ptrMyInterface.CoCreateInstance(myClsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL); // Also fails
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to watch your program searching for the registry keys.

Comment: In my case, I didn't add the rgs file for the COM Interface class.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel really kind of silly.  The problem was the fact that CComPtr was trying to call QueryInterface on the object I was CoCreating.  The Interface that I was using was not implemented by the class that I was creating.  It seems that there would be a better error than REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. Something like E_NOINTERFACE would be a better return code IMHO.

```
CComPtr<IMyCorrectInterface> ptrMyInterface;
ptrMyInterface.CoCreateInstance(L"ProgID", nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL); // WORKS!!!
```